# MySQL - InnoDB buffer pool, disable/workaround

Tags: mysql, buffer, innodb

I'm working on a system that incluces exporting large amounts of data into csv files. We are using InnoDB for the our tables. InnoDB buffers previous queries/results in some manor. 
Now on a production enviroment that is a really good thing but while testing the performance of an export in my dev enviroment it is not.
The buffer pool size seems to be Around 128MB.
I couldn't find much about this on google except that you can change some MySQL settings when the server boots up.

Anyone knows a workaround of maybe there is a sql statement that prevents it from being put into the buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a non-problem (since 5.1.41)

It is impossible to prevent any InnoDB activity from going through the buffer_pool.  It is too deeply engrained in the design.

The buffer_pool caches data and index *blocks*, not queries/results.  The Query cache plays with queries/results.  But the QC should normally be disabled for production systems.

innodb_old_blocks_pct (default = 37, meaning % of buffer_pool) prevents wiping out the buffer pool from certain operations such as the reads needed for your 'export'.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_old_blocks_pct
and the links in that section.

Comment: Thank you for replying Rick, I'm no expert in databases and there is still lots to learn!  I've managed to get the script up to an acceptable speed.

Comment: @RickJames, What's the point of the query cache anyway if production servers would typically disable them?

Comment: 5.7 (or maybe it is not until 8.0) allows you to dynamically change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` without restarting MySQL.